# Any way to get Netbeans to save before a compile and run?

Tags: netbeans, save, autosave

I'm using Netbeans for Groovy/Grails development. I'm very new to Groovy/Grails and netbeans.

Netbeans doesn't save all changed files before a compile and run. I looked through every Preference setting, the help, etc, and can't find an option to save on build.

Does such an option exist in Netbeans? I waste a lot of time forgetting to save everything before compiling and testing.

Answer (score 1):

button F9 used to do it [here](http://usersguide.netbeans.org/shortcuts.pdf).